# Gson: Remove redundant newlines when serializing an array

Tags: java, gson

When using Gson to serialize an array to json, I get a new line after each element, e.g.

```
  "values": [
    962,
    962,
    0,
    962,
    483,
    479
  ]
```

is there anyway to avoid this, and have all values in the same line within Gson (that is, not post-processing Gson's output)?

Comment: That JSON element has no newlines.  Are you asking how to change the formatting that Gson uses to print JSON objects?

Comment: I thought the compact format was default for serializing to json. How do you create the GsonBuilder?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö wow, I'm stupid. want to create a formal answer for that so I will mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *GsonBuilder* should by default compact the data when serializing to JSON. It is possible to configure it to not do this (for readability).

Example for compacting serializer

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

and for not compacting (pretty print)

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

See also [Gson doc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html).